# SilverStripe Images missing from Files and Images

Tags: image, silverstripe

I am using SilverStripe 2.4.7 and a php library to generate png images of QR codes. That is all working perfectly but I noticed that even though the images are in the folder they do not show up in the "Files & Images" part of my CMS.  I have tried flushing the cache but that doesn't help.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hang on. Found the answer.

Apparently 2.4 has a little quirk where you have to click the "Look for new files" button in the "Files & Images" tab.  This fixed my problem but is annoying for the users of the CMS.

Comment: Whenever you don't add files via the admin or programmatically, you need to import them (they are added to the database for easier handling). For performance reasons this isn't done automatically (repeatedly scanning a few hundred or thousand files for no reason doesn't sound too clever). That's the behaviour of all 2.x versions (not sure about 3.0, haven't checked yet)

Comment: If you add images via the CMS (either Files & Images or through the WYSIWYG), you shoudn't have to click "Look for new files".

Comment: They aren't added through the CMS, they are generated programmatic-ally and added to one of the folders.  My project is a little odd for SilverStripe so this feature (while the best practice in 99% of cases) doesn't meet my needs.